# Working with a List of Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of 300 dictionaries with the same format/structure. I am trying to print the same value from each dictionary with something like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk77o.png)[but I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIPXV.png)

How do I get the correspondent value to "value" since I can't subscript a number?

I am not sure how to move forward and am very new to coding but I've been told stack overflow is super helpful.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be easier to provide help if you post a minimum reproducible example ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), rather than putting the code in an image.

Comment: Specifically it would be good to know what elements the dictionary is expected to have, as well as to describe the expected outcome. 

That being said, its because you're calling `data_2[i["value"]]`, but i is defined as `range(len(data_2))`, so its a number. You probably want `data_2[i]["value"]` instead but its hard to say for sure without seeing an example of the data.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a quick response. The dictionaries read like this: {'title': '', 'media_map_data': {}, 'string_map_data': {'Interest': {'href': '', 'value': 'Chicago Bears', 'timestamp': 0}}}.    I am working on a minimum reproducible example, but it worked when I tried a second ago. Here was my attempt:                               dicti = {
    "right":"yes", 
    "wrong":"no"
    }
dictio = {
    "right":"good",
    "wrong":"bad"
}
List = [dicti, dictio]
for i in range(len(List)):
  print(List[i]["right"])

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.